# Why Read speed is very low in glusterFS with Direct I/O mode enabled?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, glusterfs

We are running our application on three node gluster. 
Case 1: With default configuration our application's write speed is 150 MBps and read speed is also same.
Case 2: With Direct I/O Mode enabled by setting below three parameters in gluster volume

```
direct-io-mode=enable
network.remote-dio           off
performance.strict-o-direct  on
```

The write speed of application improved and touched 250 MBps but read speed is very low.
For reading of 5 GB of data, it is taking approximately 20 minutes.

**Question: Why read speed is so slow in Direct I/O Mode? How can we configure gluster or anything else to achieve better reading speed in Direct I/O Mode?**

Each Node's Specification:

```
RAM: 132 GB
Processor count: 16
```

Gluster Specifications:

```
Trusted Service Pool has 3 physical nodes, With one Brick is configured on each node.
Storage Type: SSD
Gluster Version: glusterfs 3.8.4
```

Volume Specifications:

```
Type: Replicate
Number of Bricks: 1 x 3 = 3
performance.read-ahead: off
performance.cache-refresh-timeout: 1
performance.cache-size: 20GB  ( We tried lesser cache-size also like 256 MB, but in vain )
nfs.disable: on
cluster.brick-multiplex: on
Volume Size: 200 GB
```

Answer (score 0):

In these case,the reason why read speed is lower with direct IO mode is that the cache loss. you can use two command  **cachestat** and **cachetop** to find out the hits details.